# Which term would you use to describe these propagation start point?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I am building a web application and i want the user to be able to browse information that is relevant to a certain propagation method, for example propagation from `seed`, `bulb`, `rhizome`. English is not my native language and i'm having difficulty finding a suitable word/term to describe this.

I see that davesgarden.com uses the term `propagation`. Would this be the right term? 
The idea is that some plants can be grown from both seeds and bulbs for example. I want to let the user of my app select one of those to see the relevant details like `days until harvest` or `minimum germination temperature`. Should i use `propagation` as the label or would another word be more suitable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In horticulural terminology, 'propagation' refers specifically to propagating a plant, perhaps  with a hard or soft or semi ripe cutting, or slicing a rhizome or tuber into sections, each with an eye or growing point, or digging up a perennial plant and splitting it  into sections and replanting in order to increase stocks of a particular plant or plants.

I am not sure that is what you mean though - it  sounds like you might mean 'cultivation'  which is the term used for how  to grow things, usually covering the soil, water, temperature and light requirements, as well as when to plant. This latter, for vegetables, usually includes time from planting to harvest, or it may be a separate item.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Let me explain myself a bit further. My app will have a database with plant guides. These plant guides give grow information for a specific cultivar, information like sow depth, days until harvest and minimum temperature. Some cultivars, like for instance garlic, can be grown both from seeds and from bulbs. Days until harvest and sow depth will differ for seeds vs bulbs. In this case I want the user to be able to select either Seed or Bulb from a dropdown menu. Then the relevant amount of days and sow depth will be shown. This dropdownmenu needs a label.

Comment: right now that label is 'Propagation' but perhaps another term would be better. Should it be something like `grow start`? Thank you

Comment: I'd still use 'cultivation' as the overall name for the drop down menu - if the menu then lists  various methods of planting and growing, they can be  selected from there.